# Not getting tuples with NULL values when using != operator on 'char' column

Tags: mysql

I've a table where we have a column 'column_name' of type char(size 6). I wrote a query like below

```
select * from table_name where column_name != "String"
```

I was hoping to get the tuples in table which has values other than 'String' for column 'column_name' including tuples which has NULL value for column 'column_name'. But this query is not returning tuples having NULL value for column 'column_name'. Could you please help me understand why this is happening? And should my query be like this if I also want to have tuples with NULL values for column 'column_name' or is there any better way?

```
select * from table_name where ('column_name' != "String" or 'column_name' is NULL)
```

Comment: Do note that `<=>` is a non-standard MySQL extension that could be used in MySQL. I would argue though that it does not make a query any more readable or maintainable than using the far more ubiquitous `OR ... IS NOT NULL` as the used in the second query above

Comment: Yes, Paul,  I agree to that, I would use 2nd query mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!=` returns null when either or both operands are null.

You can use the null-safe equals operator `<=>` (inversed, because you want not equals):

```
not(column_name <=> 'String')
```

`<=>` will return 0, not null, when column_name is null and the right operand is not null.

Comment: So the reason for not getting tuples with NULL values is that when 'String' is compared with NULL using '!=' operator, it gives NULL instead of 1. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
select * from table_name where 
COALESCE(`column_name`, "") != "String"
```